# C++ program crashes when compiled with mcmodel=medium

Tags: c++, linux, g++, elf

C++ Program crashes with segmentation fault, when compiled with mcmodel=medium. We are using some pretty big arrays on stack and we need to enable medium mcmodel. 
I am using g++ 5.4, when i strace the application, it prints below error. Please advise on how to debug.

```
strace ./app 
execve("./app", ["./app"], [/* 65 vars */]) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Pasting the readelf output of the executable
readelf -l app

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x6e4f60
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x000000000074d0b8 0x000000000074d0b8  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x000000000074dc50 0x0000000000d4dc50 0x0000000000d4dc50
                 0x00000000000aafe0 0x00000041bf407a08  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x000000000074dda8 0x0000000000d4dda8 0x0000000000d4dda8
                 0x0000000000000250 0x0000000000000250  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00000000006b2c18 0x0000000000ab2c18 0x0000000000ab2c18
                 0x000000000000ef14 0x000000000000ef14  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000000000074dc50 0x0000000000d4dc50 0x0000000000d4dc50
                 0x00000000000003b0 0x00000000000003b0  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame .gcc_except_table 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss .lbss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got
```

kernel version: 
Linux rk-VirtualBox 4.4.0-64-lowlatency #85-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 20 12:39:25 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Have you tried using an actual debugger, like `gdb` or `lldb`? Compile your program with the `-g` flag and you should be able to pinpoint the location of your error.

Comment: @BenSteffan That's unlikely to help anything. See my answer.

Comment: Yes it didnt help much, the gdb wont show any thing informative. I have to use strace to see what is going on at the kernel level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strace` output you show suggests that the *kernel* is refusing to start your program (not a single instruction of your program is executed).

The kernel simply says: "this executable is built in such a way that I can't make it run".

Output of `readelf -l ./app` and the exact kernel version can help diagnose this further.

**Update:**

The second `LOAD` segment:

```
LOAD           0x000000000074dc50 0x0000000000d4dc50 0x0000000000d4dc50
               0x00000000000aafe0 0x00000041bf407a08  RW     200000
```

asks the kernel to allocate (`mmap`) `0x41bf407a08` bytes. That's almost 263GiB. Either your machine doesn't have that much memory, or your `ulimit -v` and `ulimit -d` are set too low, or both.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, i am pasting the output of readelf below

Comment: @RavikumarTulugu I've updated the answer.